# Is it possible to get the value of a matched RegEx? If so, how should it be done?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the code for a small syntax highlighter I made. It's supposed to search through every code tag in my `.html` file and make highlights to certain parts of it. Once this runs in the browser, I get this weird `"keyword">` text in front of every line I have a keyword in. After some debugging, I still haven't came across a solution or a reason to why this problem occurs. I did notice that when I removed the `id`s from the `code` tag, the `"keyword">` disappears, but the text still doesn't get highlighted.

If I code everything manually rather than using JavaScript to do it for me, everything works fine, but the problem is that the process is very time consuming and I have many more code snippets to do this for. Is there any way that I can get the matching keyword from `keywords` and include it in somehow? Is there a way to iterate over regular expressions like in arrays? Thanks in advance :)

image 1 (partial success):
[image: image1 (partial success)]
I had to manually add `span` tags (removed unwanted text), but then highlighting doesn't work

image 2 (error image):
[image: image2(error image)]

CSS code (inline)

```css
.keyword {color: #c792ed;}
.identifier {color: #a6acce;}
.string {color: #6401e5;}
.int {color: #f78c6a;}
.comment {color: #69aa00;}
/*
#code0, #code1
^-----> ^-----> not defined
*/
```

Html code

```html
<p>
    <code id="code0">
        let text = "I'd like 2 pizzas please"; // This is a string. It holds text characters
    </code>
    <br>
    <code id="code1">
        let ovenOn = true; // This is a Boolean. Its values are either 'true' or 'false'.
    </code>
</p>
```

JavaScript code (inline)

```js
let d = document;
let i = 0;
//----------------> Defining variables

       
function highlight() {
    let tags = d.getElementsByTagName("code");
    let reserved = "abstract arguments await boolean break byte case catch char class const continue debugger default delete do double else enum eval export extends false final finally float for function goto if implements import in instanceof int interface let long native new null package private protected public return short static super switch synchronized this throw throws transient true try typeof var void volatile while with yield";

    for(i; i<tags.length; i++){
        let code = tags[i].innerHTML;
        let keywords = new RegExp(reserved.split(' ').join('|'));
        //  ^------- keywords = ["abstract", "await", "etc..."]
        //           ^------- then becomes: keywords = /abstract|await|etc.../

        code = code.replace(keywords,   '<span class="keyword">$1</span>');
        //     ^---> Should capture the keyword in keywords (fails)
        //     ^---> see image2 

        code = code.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '<span class="string">&quot;$1&quot;</span>');
        //     ^---> captures strings and places contents between quotes (works)

        code = code.replace(/\/\/(.*)/g,'<span class="comment">// $1 </span>');
        //     ^---> captures single-line comments (works)
        tags[i].innerHTML = code;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', highlight);
// ^-----> Calling highlight();
```

Comment: Just an FYI: use a single backtick (`\``) for inline code. Three backticks create a fenced codeblock, which you didn't seem to be purposefully trying to create inside your paragraphs.

Comment: Very appreciated. I'll go and edit right away

Comment: Look at the value of `code` at each step (for example, log it). You'll see that the code that is supposed to highlight strings will also find a "string" inside of your `<span>` tag - the `"keyword"` in `<span class="keyword">` which you just inserted! - and will go ahead and destroy your HTML. I'd recommend to first HTML-encode your code (which you need to do anyway to avoid bad rendering and XSS attacks) and then match the already-encoded code (looking for `&quot;` instead of `"`, etc.).

Comment: @GruelingPine185 Not necessary - I fixed them already. Just letting you know for future reference.

Comment: You might prepare your regexp outside the loop for better performance.

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT for that. I just changed my code to use escaped apostrophes instead of quotes. Now when I run, the highlighting works on everything except for the keywords. Unfortunately, when I remove the `id="code1"`, the highlighting still breaks. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some things in the function.

```js
function highlight() {
  let tags = d.getElementsByTagName("code");

  // I moved the reserved and keyword variables out the for loop so it will not be reinitialized for every code element

  // Its best to wrap the reserved words in word boundaries so if the reserved word is inside another word, it won't get replaced.
  // Example: 'with' as a reserved word will affect 'without'
  let reserved = "\\b(abstract arguments await Boolean break byte case catch char class const continue debugger default delete do double else enum eval export extends false final finally float for function goto if implements import in instanceof int interface let long native new null package private protected public return short static super switch synchronized this throw throws transient true try typeof var void volatile while with yield)\\b";

  //'I passed a global flag to the RegExp so all occurences of a reserved word will be replaced'
  const keywords = new RegExp(reserved.split(' ').join('|'), 'g');

  // The for loop doesn't run because i wasn't initialized.
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    let code = tags[i];

    code = code.replace(keywords, `<span class="keyword">$&</span>`);

    // After it the matches and replaces the reserved word, the class of the span tag is wrapped in quotes, so i fixed the regex to skip any match that is wrapped in the html tags <>
    code = code.replace(/(?!.*>)"(.*?)"/g, '<span class="string">"$1"</span>');

    code = code.replace(/\/\/(.*)/g, '<span class="comment">// $1 </span>');
    tags[i].innerHTML = code;
  }
}


// One of your examples should return this.
// <span class="keyword">let</span> text = <span class="string">"I'd like 2 pizzas please"</span>; <span class="comment">//  This is a string. It holds text characters</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how you are writing the HTML string. If you use a template literal (backtick) instead of quotes I think you get the functionality you need.

Here's an example which I think works?

```
let reserved =
'abstract arguments await boolean'; // have simplified

const keywords = new RegExp(reserved.split(' ').join('|'));

const sample = `<code>let a = new boolean(true);</code>`;

const example = `<span class="keyword">$1</span>`;

console.log(sample.replace(keywords, example));

/* Returns:
<code>
let a = new <span class="keyword">$1</span>(true);
</code>
*/
```